# Axes Properties - Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, properties, axes

I need to know how to remove the numbers from X and Y axes.
I'm don't think this is related to the X grid or Y grid because in the axes Inspector
the XGrid and YGrid is in off state.

[image]

I tried all but it did not help.

**edit:** [image]

thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler solution is

```
axis off
```

but it comes with a caveat: it also removes the `x` and `y` labels. So if you wanted to include labels and remove only the numbers, nibot's answer is the correct way to go.

Comment: @yoda, I actually always used more complex `set(gca,'Visible','off')`. +1 for the simple way with the same effect.

Comment: @yoda thanks for your answer. is there a way to do this from the axes Inspector? because if I'm click on the picture the numbers returns. thanks.

Comment: @Michael: I'm not sure what you mean by the axes inspector.. If you mean the plot browser, then there should be a checkbox with "Axes (no name)" or some name if you've given one. By unchecking that, you can achieve the same effect.

Comment: @yoda when I'm click on the axes there is the menu, in that menu there is the property inspector. I added a picture in the question above. thanks again.

Comment: @Michael: Ah, in that case you need to turn the property `'Visible'` to `'off'`.

Comment: @Michael: It should work. Perhaps you looked in the wrong section? The property is in `Base Properties > Visible`

Comment: @yoda I did it just like you said, but it still do the same. when I'm loading picture to the axes the axes is Becomes visible and then when I click the picture the numbers is shown again. thanks again...

Answer (score 3):

```
set(gca, 'XTick', [], 'YTick', [])
```